# Dijkstra's implementation in c++ with STL priority_queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, object-oriented, graph

This is dijkstras shortest path algorithm implementation in c++ using priority_queue STL.

Looking for two things: a) Correctness of algorithm itself and b) Any improvement suggestions.

```
/*                  3
    ----->  b   ----------->d
 10/ -1--  ^  |     1    ^/ |
  / /      |  |   ------// 1|
 x v      2|11|  / /-1--    |
  \        |  v / v         V
   \----->  c  -----------> e
     1             8
*/
class EdgeNode
{
  public:
  char label;
  int weight;
  EdgeNode(char l = 0, int w = 0) : label(l), weight(w) {}
};

using EdgeNodes = vector<EdgeNode *>;


class Graph
{
  public:
  unordered_map<char, EdgeNodes *> adj;

  void addNode(char node)
  {
    if(adj.find(node) == adj.end()) {
      adj[node] = new EdgeNodes();
    }
  }
  void addEdge(char start, char end, int weight)
  {
    if(adj.find(start) != adj.end()) {
      for(auto node : *adj[start]) {
        if(node->label == end) {
          node->weight = weight;
          return;
        }
      }
    } else {
      adj[start] = new EdgeNodes();
    }
    if(end) {
        adj[start]->push_back(new  EdgeNode(end, weight));
    }
  }

  void get_parent(unordered_map<char, char>& parent, char c)
  { 
    cout << "Parent chain of \'" << c << "\' =";
    while((parent.find(c) != parent.end()) && parent[c]) {
      cout << parent[c] << ", ";
      c = parent[c];
   }
    cout << endl;
  }

  void get_distance(unordered_map<char, int>& dist)
  {
    cout << "distances => ";
    for(auto a : dist) {
       cout << "(" << a.first << "=" << a.second << ")  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  void djikstras()
  {
    unordered_set<char> visited;
    unordered_map<char, int> dist;
    unordered_map<char, char> parent;

    using Pair = pair<char, int>;
    priority_queue<Pair, vector<Pair>, greater<Pair>> pq; 
    char snode = 'x';

    visited.insert(snode);
    dist[snode] = 0;
    parent[snode] = 0;
    pq.push(make_pair(snode, 0));

    while(!pq.empty()) {
      Pair front = pq.top(); pq.pop();
      for(EdgeNode *edge : *adj[front.first]) {
        if(visited.find(edge->label) == visited.end()) {
          dist[edge->label] = dist[front.first] + edge->weight;
          visited.insert(edge->label);
          parent[edge->label] = front.first; 
          pq.push(make_pair(edge->label, dist[edge->label]));
        } else {
          /* //Parent comparison not needed in directed graph for djikstras
             //Its anyways useless because distance back to parent will always be larger
          if(parent[front.first] == edge->label) {
             cout << "Parent " << front.first << " = " <<  parent[front.first] << endl;
             continue;
          }*/
          if(dist[edge->label] > (dist[front.first] + edge->weight)) {
            dist[edge->label] = dist[front.first] + edge->weight;
            parent[edge->label] = front.first;
            pq.push(make_pair(edge->label, dist[edge->label]));
          }   
        }   
      }   
    }   
    get_distance(dist);
    get_parent(parent, 'e');
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  Graph g;
  g.addEdge('x', 'c', 1); g.addEdge('x', 'b', 10);
  g.addEdge('b', 'x', 1);  g.addEdge('b', 'c', 11); g.addEdge('b', 'd', 3);
  g.addEdge('c', 'b', 2);  g.addEdge('c', 'd', 1);  g.addEdge('c', 'e', 8);
  g.addEdge('d', 'c', 1);  g.addEdge('d', 'e', 1);
  g.addNode('e');

  g.djikstras();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448361/14065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohhh. Don't do this:

```
using EdgeNodes = vector<EdgeNode *>;
unordered_map<char, EdgeNodes *> adj;
```

Now you need to manage the memory of the `EdgeNodes`. Simply declare it as a value type:

```
using EdgeNodes = vector<EdgeNode>;      // Remove the star
unordered_map<char, EdgeNodes>      adj; // Remove the star.
```

To make the rest of your code simpler I would define a way to compare the EdgeNodes.

```
class EdgeNode
{
  public:
  char label;
  int weight;
  EdgeNode(char l = 0, int w = 0) : label(l), weight(w) {}

  // Compare a Node against a label
  bool operator==(char l) {return label == l;}
};
```

This makes your add functions simpler:

```
  void addNode(char node)
  {
      adj.insert({node, EdgeNodes{}});
  }
  void addEdge(char start, char end, int weight)
  {
      auto& dest = adj[node].second;

      // See if there is already a link to the destination.
      // This uses the `operator==` we defined above to compare
      // each node against `end`.
      auto  find = std::find(std::begin(dest), std::end(dest), end);

      if (find != std::end(dest)) {
          // If we already have it update the weight.  
          find->weight = weight;
      }
      else {
          // otherwise add it to the end.
          dest.emplace_back(end, weight);
      }
  }
```

Don't be lazy:

```
  Pair front = pq.top(); pq.pop();
```

Split it over two lines. Its easy to write new code. Its hard to read other people's code. Don't make it difficult for them.

```
  Pair front = pq.top();   // Get the top item
  pq.pop();                // Pop it from the queue.
```

The dijkstras algorithm looks ok.

Things to look at:

- I find it a bit dense to read and it took me a while to understand it but nothing technically wrong with it.
- I might have used a single map for `parent/distance` calculations rather than two distinct structures.
- Checking inclusion in the visited list is usually done on the node as it is popped of the `dq` not when pushing it onto the list. This may be a bug.
- Normall you pass `start` and `end` as parameters to `djikstras`

Let me re-try a refactor:

```
void djikstras(char snode, char end)
{
    using ParentEdge = std::pair<char, EdgeNode>;
    auto  comp = [](ParentEdge const& l, ParentEdge const& r){return l.second.weight < r.second.weight;};

    unordered_map<char, EdgeNode>                        retrace;    
    priority_queue<ParentEdge, vector<ParentEdge>, comp> pq; 

    // special case the snode is its own parent.
    retrace[snode]   = EdgeNode(snode, 0);
    pq.push(ParentEdge(snode, EdgeNode(snode, 0)));

    while(!pq.empty()) {
        // Get details of next node.
        ParentEdge front   = pq.top();
        char&      parent  = front.first;
        char&      current = front.second.label;
        int&       weight  = front.second.weight;
        pq.pop();

        if (current === end) {
            // Did we find the destination.
            printRoute(retrace, end);
            return;
        }

        if (retrace.find(current) != retrace.end()) {
            // Already found cheapest route to here.
            continue;
        }

        // Found cheapest route to this point. Add info to the structures.
        retrace[current]  = EdgeNode(parent, retrace[parent].weight + weight);

        // Add children to the frontier list
        for(EdgeNode edge : adj[current]) {
            pq.push(ParentEdge(current, edge));
        }
    }  
    std::cout << "Failed to find route from start to finish\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Forgot why I did pointer thingy, but agree with you. About the splitting on two lines, I with we had pq.pop_and_assign() function.
Any comments on dijkstra's algo itself?

Comment: @PnotNP The algorithm I find to hard to read (way to dense). I provided a comment on the answer to a simpler implementation I wrote.

Comment: @PnotNP Tried to refactor your djikstras. Have not compiled it so it may need some work.